# negative values in normalized data

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataset excel file which is normalized but it contains negative values that causes some of my prediction results become negative. Is it normal to have negative values among my normalized dataset? because as I know a normalized dataset values are between 0 and 1.

I tried to normalize it again but my MAPE value become a very large number something like 7568839.743593587, which shows that I have an issue.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail on how you performed normalization, if possible before and after values as sample to reproduce the issue? If your data already has a negative value, i suggest to add the most minimal value to make all the values positive first before running the normalization.

Comment: These are before and after values:
4838.665376,

4845.176609,

5157.99566,

0.393156071,

0.393833589,

0.426383594

and the formula I used in Excel file is:
=IF((A2 - $E$1) <> 0, (A2 - $E$1) / ($F$1 - $E$1), A2)

Comment: Your first step should be to shift your data by `abs(min(observations))`. then normalize

Comment: At least in the simplest form of normalization. It is possible that your data is normalized in some manner that is not "min-max feature scaling" but I think that is what you are looking to achieve right? If so you can take your data and apply "min-max feature scaling" by shifting you data and then doing the normalization to get a observations between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a conceptual implementation you might be looking for in steps:

```
## INITIAL DATA 'ls'
ls = [-5, 5, 10, 15, 20, -10]

## MAKE ALL VALUES POSITIVE BY ADDING ABSOLUTE VALUE OF THE MINIMUM
new_ls = [item + abs(min(ls)) for item in ls]
print(new_ls)
# returns: [5, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0]

## NORMALIZATION STEP
norm_values = [(x - min(ls)) / (max(ls) - min(ls)) for x in new_ls]
print(norm_values)
# returns [0.5, 0.8333333333333334, 1.0, 1.1666666666666667, 1.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333]
```